# setting a variable to each element of an array

Tags: javascript

i have function:

```
function getFieldNames(arrayOfRecords) {
var theStuff;
for (var i = 0; i = arrayOfRecords.length - 1; i++){
    theStuff = arrayOfRecords[i];
    theList = theStuff.split('" ');
    for (var j = 0; j = theList.length - 1; j++) {
        var v = theList[j].split('="');
        fName1[i][j] = v[0];
        }
    }
return fName1;
}
```

the argument arrayOfRecords is an array, and i dont know how to setup to the 'theStuff' variable an array element? When I do like it is above, i get something stupid.

can anyone help me? :)

Comment: What the type of data stored in this array `arrayOfRecords`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other problems but the one that leaps out at me is your `for` loop header:

```
for (var i = 0; i = arrayOfRecords.length - 1; i++)
```

The second part should be a condition, which when evaluated to `false` will stop the loop from running. What you probably wanted was:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfRecords.length; i++)
```

So when `i` is not less than `arrayOfRecords.length`, the loop will stop. Alternatively (to keep the `- 1`, but I tend to use the above version):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= arrayOfRecords.length - 1; i++)
```

The same goes for the nested loop.

Comment: ok i think that this was a problem too (thanks i didnt saw it before!) but now to variable theStuff i only get the first letter from array element.